# Chage the color and opacity of Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows, colors, windows-10, taskbar

Is there a way to change the color of Windows 10 taskbar and decrease its opacity? Also changing the color of the start and making it a little bit different?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps

- Press Win + R
- Write regedit
- Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows ->
  Explorer -> Advance
- Right Click -> New and select your system (32 bit or 64 bit)
- Name it UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency
- Right click UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency and make value = 1
- Click Ok
- Right Click to Desktop and go to Personalise
- Click Colors from right
- At the bottom of window you can see Make Start, taskbar and Action
  Centre Transparent

Or you have to install third part application from [http://startisback.com/](http://startisback.com)

Comment: Yes, you explain your answer better!